# Question about X concentrates to its mean

Tags: concentration-of-measure

Suppose for a statistic $X$ of a size-n sample, $E|X-EX|\le f(n)$ for some decreasing function $f(n)$. Can we say $X$ concentrates to its mean at a rate of $f(n)$?

I understand concentration rate is often defined by how the tail probability concentrates. But in this mean concentration case, can we still call $f(n)$ the concentration rate? If not, what is the proper way to call this? Thanks.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. For $E[X - E[X]] = 0$, always.

Comment: @ Kaind. It is |.|, not [.] in the expectation.

Comment: Why not just use the variance?

Comment: @ Kaind. Because this absolute deviation is commonly used in concentration inequalities.